# Excel Macro for XML Data Modification

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I'm looking to generate an excel macro and was hoping to get some direction. What I am trying to do is take data from 5 XML files and put them into a new workbook and then graph the resulting data in line graph format. The data in the XML files is the same in all 5 files and is in the format displayed below:

```
<Sample Secs="25313">
    <Pout>215280</Pout>
</Sample>
<Sample Secs="25562">
    <Pout>233627</Pout>
</Sample>
```

Which, when opened in Excel as an XML table, gets displayed as:

```
25313   215280
25562   233627
```

with the headers of "Secs" and "Pout", respectively. The "Secs" column is common between all 5 files in Column A and then the unique data is in the "Pout" column which is located in Column B. There are going to be approximately 1500 data points in each file for Column B. What I would like to accomplish is having all 5 XML files opened,  the unique data pulled from each file, and then the data graphed. Before graphing, I would like the new Excel workbook to look be formatted like this:

```
Secs  Pout1  Pout2  Pout3  Pout4  Pout5
```

with the data for "Secs" coming from any of the 5 files (as it is common) and the Column B data being put in the respective Pout# column.

Is there a way to have Excel VBA do this and how exactly would I go about setting this up?

Comment: What coding have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  for more information.

```
 Option Explicit

    Private Sub LoadXmlData()

    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument60
    Dim sSecs As String, sPout As String
    Dim iNodes As Integer, i As Integer, t As Integer
    Dim sPath1 As String, sPath2 As String, sPath3 As String, _
        sPath4 As String, sPath5 As String, sTempPath As String

    Range("A1").Value2 = "Secs"
    'Set the file paths of your xml documents here

    sPath1 = ""
    sPath2 = ""
    sPath3 = ""
    sPath4 = ""
    sPath5 = ""

    For t = 0 To 4
        Select Case t
            Case 0
                sTempPath = sPath1
            Case 1
                sTempPath = sPath2
            Case 2
                sTempPath = sPath3
            Case 3
                sTempPath = sPath4
            Case 4
                sTempPath = sPath5
        End Select

        xmlDoc.Load (sTempPath)
        iNodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Length

        'Fill in the first column with the values from the attribute Secs
        'Only do it once because the values are the same in each file
        If t = 0 Then
            For i = 0 To iNodes - 1
                Range("A" & i + 2).Value2 = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(i).Attributes.Item(0).Text
            Next i
        End If

        'Fill in the Pout column
        Cells(1, t + 1).Value2 = "Pout" & t + 1
        For i = 0 To iNodes - 1
            Cells(i + 2, t + 1).Value2 = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(i).nodeTypedValue
        Next i
    Next t

End Sub
```